# Insert data from an API on the database - Django project

Tags: python, django

I would like to save product data from an API in a table in my database that I created

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
  code=models.CharField(max_length=70,primary_key=True)
  designation=models.TextField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.product.code
```

views.py

```
from .models import Product

def products(request):
  url='http://myAPI/Product/GetProducts'
  x=requests.get(url)
  content=x.json()
  all_product=content['products']
  for product in all_product:
     product=Product()
     product.save()
  return render(request,'cart/product.html',context)
```

How to proceed to insert each product in the table with the for loop ??
Note that each product is characterized by a code and a designation

Comment: `Product(**product)`…?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: You're not using the JSON data anywhere, you're just creating empty `Product` instances. You may want to pass the JSON data to those instances as shown above…?

Comment: can you share your api response? `all_product`

Comment: how to pass an instance of each product to my product boject.
to save it in my database

Comment: @Hémal Patel, all_product=[{'code':'211AP','designation':'orange'},...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do bulk_create:

```
def products(request):
  url='http://myAPI/Product/GetProducts'
  x=requests.get(url)
  content=x.json()
  all_product=content['products']
  
  create_obj = []
  for product in all_product:    
      create_obj.append(Product(code=product['code'],
                        designation=product['designation']))
  product_data = Product.objects.bulk_create(create_obj)
  return render(request,'cart/product.html',{"product_data":product_data} )
```